# Extract some fields from a data class for serialization

Tags: c#, interface, xmlserializer

I would like serialize some stuff.
For now the program serializes my whole data class with 15 fields in it and writes it in a txt-file.
I would like to split serialization of my data class in two parts: it should serialize and write the first 8 fields in txtFile_A, and on other occasion serialize und write the second 7 fields in txtFile_B.

I tried to split my data class with the help of interfaces.

```
public class PuppiesAndKittens: IPuppies
{
    public bool PuppyEats { get; set; }
    public bool PuppyBarks { get; set; }
    //...
}

public interface IPuppies
{
    bool PuppyEats { get; set; }
    bool PuppyBarks { get; set; }
    //....
}
```

Serialization part:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
{
    XmlSerializer s;

    s = new XmlSerializer((PuppiesAndKittensInstance as IPuppies).GetType());

    // I would expect here the type of IPuppies, but the type is still PuppiesAndKittens. It contains all 15 fields and not the needed 8 for the txtfile_A

    s.Serialize(sw, (PuppiesAndKittensInstance as IPuppies));
}
```

After the serialization I write this information down to a txtfile.

The question is, if this is generally possible and I miss something in the code?  I have other options to solve the problem, which are less preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing an interface alone does not affect the serialization process because the `XmlSerializer` uses the actual type of the object being serialized, not the interface type. Therefore, casting `PuppiesAndKittensInstance` to `IPuppies` does not change the serialization behavior.
One option would be to create a separate class for each field you want to serialize and populate those with the necessary fields from your original class.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answer said, your *actual* instance is still `PuppiesAndKittensInstance` and that's all the serializer cares.

A workaround the other answer suggested is to create a "copy" with only desired properties. Another solution is to use [`XmlIgnoreAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute?view=net-7.0). Also see [Control XML serialization using attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes#preventing-serialization-with-the-xmlignoreattribute).

```cs
public class PuppiesAndKittens: IPuppies
{
    public bool PuppyEats { get; set; }
    public bool PuppyBarks { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore] // This property won't be serialized
    public bool SomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```